# ThreadPoolExecutor too many positional arguments

Tags: python

I have a [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) in the following class:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

    def add_callback(self, k):
        fut = self.__pool.submit(self.fn, self, k)
        print(str(fut.exception()))

    def fn(self, k):
        print(k)
```

If I execute something like

```
x_object = X()
x_object.add_callback(5)
```

I get the following exception:

```
fn() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Where is this 3rd argument coming from that the thread pool executor is trying to call `fn()` with?

Comment: An object of type X, like `x_object = X()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
    fut = self.__pool.submit(self.fn, k)
```

is enough. `self` must not be an argument to [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit).